# Двойные скобки в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот такой код

```
df = google.history(period='1d', interval="1m") # pandas DataFrame
df = df[['Low']]
df.head()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я правильно понимаю, что предпоследняя строчка равносильно `df = df['Low']`, только она пересохраняет переменную, а не использует ее как указатель? или `['Low']` и есть ключ в dict и мы пересохраняем в list?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-select-a-subset-of-a-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы объект `df` в Вашем коде был словарем (`dict`), то выражение

```
df = df[['Low']]
```

нарушало бы синтаксис и Вы получили бы исключение

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

так как интерпретатор бы посчитал, что Вы пытаетесь использовать список `['Low']` как ключ словаря, а изменяемые значения не могут быть ключами словарей.

В Вашем случае речь идет об объектах библиотеки `pandas` и мы не получим объекты типа `dict` и `list`.

В Вашем коде `df` представляет собой объект библиотеки `pandas` `pandas.Dataframe`, поэтому выражение:

```
df = df[['Low']]
```

создает объект такого же типа `pandas.Dataframe` (если быть точным `class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'`). То есть таблицу с одной колонкой с именем `Low`.

В то время как выражение

```
df = df['Low']
```

создаст объект типа `pandas.Series` (`class 'pandas.core.series.Series'`), то есть просто одну колонку.

В обоих случаях изначальный `df` будет перезаписан.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = google.history(period='1d', interval="1m") # pandas DataFrame
# Здесь df  получает, скорее всего, датафрейм


df = df[['Low']]
# Здесь df Стирает все что  полученно выше и при сваивает один столбик 'Low'

df.head()
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав кнопку [edit].